# Blazor 500 error downloading app.css from CSS folder

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have my app.css in the wwwroot/css folder and i'm getting a 500 error during page load.  No css files in that folder will load.  If i move the app.css up one level to wwwroot then it works.  I created an xxx folder under the css folder and putting the css there is successful.

/wwwroot/css/app.css  - 500 error

/wwwroot/app.css - success

/wwwroot/css/xxx/app.css - success

What could be going wrong here?  I'm on VS17.8.0 Preview 1, with .NET 8, using the new Blazor Web App project which initially renders server side then switches to WASM.  I'm using IIS Express and Edge.

I tried loading from app.razor and from index.razor - same results.

I'm having a similar problem with some js

Update:  I created a mycss folder at the same level as the css folder, with the same results.

/wwwroot/mycss/app.css - 500 error

/wwwroot/mycss/xxx/app.css - success

Thinking the "CSS" was trouble, i created a folder mystuff with the same results.

/wwwroot/mystuff/app.css - 500 error
/wwwroot/mystuff/xxx/app.css - success

Comment: Somewhere I bet the CSS word is protected, the easy solution is make a new directory and use that like /bincss or something.  THAT or you can spend the time finding out why this is happening and what system is blocking it.  My money is on a rule being set that is overriding your front end code.  (also binjs perhaps?  I know its hacky but its fast fix if you have work to do and can patch it later.

Comment: i had a typo in the orig q - fixed above.  the xxx folder i created was under css, so /wwwroot/css/xxx/app.css was successful.

I tried your suggestion, tho, by creating a mycss folder and copying everything into there.  same results as above.  

/wwwroot/mycss/app.css - 500
/wwwroot/mycss/xxx/app.css - success

Comment: Fair enough , what about your web.config file?  Maybe theres a rule in there about CSS and JS ?

Comment: this is a blazor app so it uses appsettings.json instead, and is MUCH short than web.config.  I'm using the default that is generated with the project

{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

Comment: BTW, my index.razor page is empty.
@page "/"
<br/>

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is here.  If you create a new BlazorWasm project, by default the `app.css` is in `wwwroot/css/`,  I would create a new project and compare yours to it

Comment: ^ there you go thats a good idea

Comment: In your `wwwroot/index.html` file, the CSS is referenced by this line `<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: a new project works.  i'll start moving pieces over to see when it breaks

Comment: I found the problem.  I had a page called Region.razor.  This was prolly conflicting with the reserved word.  Renaming the page fixed it, but only after also restarting VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I had a page called Region.razor that was throwing an exception in OnInitialized.  One of the  params for this page was a string i use to look up some things, and that param was receiving all the CSS and JS declarations from app.razor. It was very odd.

Anyway, this page was prolly conflicting with the reserved word. Renaming the page fixed it, but only after also restarting VS.